# Проблемы с кодировкой при переносе сайта на сервер

Tags: php, кодировка

Сайт стоял на OpenServer на моей машине, затем перенёс его на хостинг от reg.ru. Итог — все данные, которые идут из PHP-скриптов, отображаются как `????????`. Что делать? Где поменять кодировку PHP? Уже попробовал в `.htaccess` добавить кодировку дефолтную и в `<head>` добавить `Content-Type`, ничего не помогает.

Comment: данные идут из БД ?

Comment: @varz62 Да, данные идут из БД. Кодировка в БД - utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

после подключения к БД выполните запросы

$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")

$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'")

$mysqli->query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'")

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте в php добавить заголовок

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8', true);
```